# Как программно задать свойства для edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-xml

Прошу помощи!! Есть кнопка, которая создаёт новый edittext в constraintlayout. Как программно задать для него положение на экране относительно других элементов:

android:layout_marginStart

android:layout_marginTop

app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf

app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf

app:layout_constraintWidth_percent

(n изначально равна 8)

onCreate

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                n++;
                ConstraintLayout laybridge = findViewById(R.id.laybridge);
                EditText newEditText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                EditText name8 = findViewById(R.id.name8);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = name8.getLayoutParams();
                newEditText.setLayoutParams(params);                
                int name_id = laybridge.getResources().getIdentifier("name".concat(String.valueOf(n)), "id", getPackageName());
                newEditText.setId(name_id);
                laybridge.addView(newEditText);
            }

        });
```

уже существующий edittext

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name8"
                    style="@style/ETon2Layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name7"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".32" />
```

новый edittext должен получиться таким

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name9"
                    style="@style/ETon2Layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name8"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".32" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать соответствующий LayoutParams и отдать вьюшке. Примерно так

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        lp.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
        lp.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
        lp.setMarginEnd(10);
        lp.setMarginStart(10);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Учти, setMarginStart(10) - это 10 пикселей, а не 10dp. Чтобы указывать в dp надо пиксели домножить на коэффициент, полученный из данных о дисплее

Еще может потребоваться вызвать requestLayout() для ConstraintLayout после установки LayoutParams и добавления вьюшки